# How to pass a value that is after colon in Watir

Tags: regex

I have an html that looks like

CLASS="ABC" width="10%">xyz: 456

I want to use 456 as value in some other parameter.

Could you please let me know how we can do that?

Comment: Some more information would be handy. Are you doing this in JavaScript on the client, or some server-side language?

Comment: I am writing a Ruby script to automate some of the stuff

Comment: And it is on the client side....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "xyz:" is mandatory and 456 will always be some sort of number and not any other data type then this Regex will do the trick:

```
xyz: ([0-9]+)
```

Tested using Rubular:
http://rubular.com/r/iilzY7gwuE